# Multiple Order By with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I start with a basic class that I want to manipulate in a List using LINQ, something like the following:

```
public class FooBar   
{  
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }  
    public virtual string Foo { get; set; }  
    public virtual string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I ultimately found out to solve my problem using the non lambda LINQ stuff.

```
// code somewhere else that works and gets the desired results  
var foobarList = GetFooBarList();  // Abstracted out - returns List<Foobar>  

// Interesting piece of code that I want to examine
var resultSet = from foobars in foobarList  
                orderby foobars.Foo, foobars.Bar  
                select foobars;

// Iterate and do something interesting  
foreach (var foobar in resultSet)  
{  
    // Do some code  
}
```

What I'm really curious about is if the same can be accomplished using the Lambda based extension methods off of generic `IEnumerable` to accomplish the same thing.  Google tells me I can do something like the following to accomplish it:

```
var resultSet = foobarList.OrderBy(x => new {x.Foo, x.Bar})  
                          .Select(x=>x);
```

However if I do that I get a runtime error when I hit the `foreach` statement.  The error tells me that at least one object has to implement `IComparible`, which I can see that since I'm using an anonymous type for the `.OrderBy()` method.

So is there a way to accomplish what I want using the Lambda way?

Comment: If you want to know what the "fluent methods" are corresponding to every possible query expression, read section 7.15.2 of the specification.

Comment: @Eric Lippert, there's a C# 3.0 Query Expression Translation Cheat Sheet, written by Bart Desmet, which I found very useful as a quick reference: http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/08/30/c-3-0-query-expression-translation-cheat-sheet.aspx .

Answer (score 614, accepted):

You can use the [ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby.aspx) and [ThenByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenbydescending.aspx) extension methods:

```
foobarList.OrderBy(x => x.Foo).ThenBy( x => x.Bar)
```

Comment: Guess I should fully get through the API before asking the question ;)  It also looks like you can chain .ThenBy() statements as many times as you need to.  Thanks again!

Comment: what about `.AndThen()`

Comment: `No .AndThen()!`

Comment: (function AndThen() { AndThen() })()

Comment: NOTE: `.OrderBy()` and `.ThenBy()` return an IOrderedEnumerable, which does **not** modify the original object.  So, you need to assign to a variable and end with `ToList()` to use the new ordered list elsewhere.

Comment: A little ashamed that I haven't known about this before in my 6 years of developing......

Comment: By default ASC? what about strings