# How to order by two fields?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

How to order by `StartDate` and `UserLikeProduct`? I need to sort by `StartDate` but show by `UserLikeProduct` first.

```
public IEnumerable<Check> GetHomeCeeck()
{    
    return this.Query()
               .Where(c => c.IsPublish && c.IsHomepageProduct)
               .OrderBy(c => c.StartDate)
               .Take(30)
               .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to order by one and then the other?

use `.ThenBy(lambda)` after the `.OrderBy(lambda)`.

If this is not what you meant then let me know and I'll remove this answer

```
.OrderBy(c => c.StartDate).ThenBy(c => c.Like)
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'asc'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'asc'.

Source Error:


Line 25:         {
Line 26: 
Line 27:             return this.Query().Where(c => c.IsPublish && c.IsHomepageProduct).OrderBy(c=>c.StartDate).ThenBy(c=>c.UserLikeProduct).Take(30).ToList();
Line 28:         }
Line 29:

Comment: @smartboy What data type is 'UserLikeProduct'? Is it an IComparable? Although that may not matter since this is trying to generate SQL

Answer (score 1):

See this question: [Multiple Order By with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318885/multiple-order-by-with-linq)

You need to OrderBy() and then ThenBy().