# Lambda Expressions, Compare item1, if they are equal compare item2

Tags: c#, sorting

I tried to search but I cannot seem to find my answer. I think an answer may exist as it not a uncommon question. I trying to say Sort by Item1. If they are equal, sort by Item2

```
sorted.Sort((a,b)=>(a.Item1.CompareTo(b.Item1)));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple Order By with LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318885/multiple-order-by-with-linq)

Answer (score 2):

While you *can* build a comparer to do this with `List<T>.Sort`, it's much easier to use LINQ, which is built for this sort of thing:

```
sorted = unsorted.OrderBy(x => x.Item1).ThenBy(x => x.Item2).ToList();
```

If you really want to use Sort, you can use the `ProjectionEqualityComparer` in my [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) project - but it won't be as nice as the LINQ approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sorted = original.OrderBy(c => c.Item1).ThenBy(n => n.Item2).ToList()
```

Try this

Comment: You're not using the result, so it won't do anything useful.

Comment: submitted too quickly. Fixed

Comment: Note that this won't be a `List<T>`, which is probably what the OP expected.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the LINQ methods, you can create a comparer:

```
class FrobComparer : IComparer<Frob>
{
    public int Compare(Frob x, Frob y)
    {
        int item1Comparison = x.Item1.CompareTo(y.Item1);

        if (item1Comparison == 0)
            return x.Item2.CompareTo(y.Item2);
        return item1Comparison;
    }
}
```

And then pass that into `Sort()`, assuming `unsorted` is a `List<Frob>`:

```
var sorted = unsorted.Sort(new FrobComparer());
```