# Group and enumerate in linq

Tags: c#, linq

Excuse me, How I can get this result in linq? Some tips?

```
List<Test> listTests = new List<Test>();

var item1 = new Test() { NumberFac = 915170958, Description = "aa" };

var item2 = new Test() { NumberFac = 915170956, Description = "bb" };

var item3 = new Test() { NumberFac = 915176287, Description = "cc" };

var item4 = new Test() { NumberFac = 915170956, Description = "dd" };

var item5 = new Test() { NumberFac = 915176287, Description = "aa" };

var item6 = new Test() { NumberFac = 915170958, Description = "mm" };

var item7 = new Test() { NumberFac = 915176287, Description = "ll" };

listTests.Add(item1);

listTests.Add(item2);

listTests.Add(item3);

listTests.Add(item4);

listTests.Add(item5);

listTests.Add(item6);

listTests.Add(item7);
```

Result

```
 #Num |NumberFac|Description

   1   |915170958| aa

   2   |915170958| mm

   1   |915170956| bb

   2   |915170956| dd

   1   |915176287| cc

   2   | 915176287| aa

   3   |915176287 | ll
```

Comment: What have you tried so far. We're here to help. Show some attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318885/multiple-order-by-with-linq)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
var result = listTests
    .GroupBy(e => e.NumberFac)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select((e, i) => new { Num = i + 1, e.NumberFac, e.Description }))
    .ToList();
```

First, [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.110).aspx) is used to group items by `NumberFac`, then [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) to flatten the result, and a special overload of [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx) that provides element index for producing the `#Num` inside the group.